# Create Extension method for IObservable

Tags: c#-4.0, system.reactive

I need to bring some data into an IObservable stream. I want to use an extension method on IObservable to do this, but i am not sure how to do it.

The data is produced by a simple class that has this signature:

```
interface Process<TIn, TOut> {
    void Do(TIn data);
    event Action<TOut> Result;
}
```

i.e. to start the process I have to call `Do(...)` and the result is sent to the event `Result(...)`. This can't be changed!

I want to bring this data into an Rx process, that handles user input in this way:

```
subject.AsObservable<string>   // this produces the observable of user inputs
       .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(typingDelay))
       .DistinctUntilChanged()

       .Process(myProcess)     // this is what I need help for

       .Switch()
       .Subscribe(myConsumer)
```

This is from adopted from the standard example of delayed user input triggering a web service (or something else that is long-running and has to be async) in the [Hands-on Labs](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=208528).

Whenever the user continues to enter, all observables that are still "underway" must be cancelled (therefore the `Switch()`). So my `Process()` has to return an `IObservable<IObservable<TOut>>` to make the switch work correctly.

I'm really stuck here. Does anyone has a hint for me how to write this `Process(...)` extension method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your `Process` interface to use generics properly and provided a dummy implementation of the interface like so:

```
interface IProcess<T, R>
{
    void Do(T data);
    event Action<IEnumerable<R>> Result;
}

public class ProcessImpl<T, R> : IProcess<T, R>
{
    public void Do(T data) { }
    public event Action<IEnumerable<R>> Result;
}
```

Now you can write the extension method like this:

```
public static IObservable<IObservable<R>> Process<T, R>(this T @this)
{
    return Observable.Create<IObservable<R>>(o =>
    {
        var p = new ProcessImpl<T, R>();
        var subscription =
            Observable
                .FromEvent<IEnumerable<R>>(
                    h => p.Result += h,
                    h => p.Result -= h)
                .Take(1)
                .Select(x => x.ToObservable())
                .Subscribe(o);
        p.Do(@this);
        return subscription;
    });
}
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Sorry, i guess i confused you by using `IEnumerable<...>` as data type. Thanks for generalizing my example, i changed it accordingly. But that shows that R = `IEnumerable<...>` so your solution does not work anymore. But this `FromEvent` looks promising, I will try to figure it out using that.

Comment: I managed it this way now: 
    IObservable<TResult> obs =  Observable.FromEvent<TResult>(
          handler => process.Result += handler,
          handler => process.Result -= handler);
    source.Subscribe(process.Process);
    return Observable.Return(obs);

nonethelesse was `FromEvent` the essential information, so i marked this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your `Process` extension method needs to subscribe to the source observable and output another.  Something like:

```
public static IObservable<TOut> Process<TIn, TOut>(this IObservable<TIn> source, IProcess<TIn, TOut> processor)
{
    return Observable.Create((IObserver<TOut> obs) =>
        {
            var sourceSub = source.Subscribe(processor.Do);
            var outSub = Observable.FromEvent<TOut>(h => processor.Result += h,
                                                    h => processor.Result -= h)
                                   .Subscribe(obs);
            return new System.Reactive.Disposables.CompositeDisposable(sourceSub, outSub);
        });
}
```

I don't think that Switch will do what you are hoping it will.  All Switch will do is end one subscription when another observable becomes available.  However, ending the subscription cannot cancel any running calls to the interface method `Process.Do`.  The cancellation you are talking about will need to be handled by the interface implementation itself.

Comment: THe cancellation is exactly what Switch does, according to the HOL i linked in my question (#9 to #11 from page 35 on).

Comment: @okrumnow Gideon is right. Switch does not cancel the old sequence. It unsubscribes from it, i.e. it stops receiving messages. But this doesn't mean that the old sequence stops. It may do whatever it wants if it doesn't support cancellation. Another question is wether you care or not: if your processor task is not resource-consuming, then you probably could forget about it and let it finish its job in background.

Comment: @PavelGatilov Thank you for this clarification. Indeed I didn't notice this difference. But for me it'll be sufficient to stop receiving messages.

Comment: @okrumnow As further clarification, the difference between this situation and the lab is that each observable in the lab only reports results to the original observable.  Your situation uses an event, meaning that every observable would get results from all running calls to Do.